# SQL Server : get columns based on MAX(SUM()) of other column

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I've ran into trouble trying to select columns based on the max of a sum of a column. I'm using SQL Server.

I have the following three tables (simplified)

**DimensionTable**

| SupplierID | ProductID | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 500 |
| 1 | 2 | 2000 |
| 1 | 3 | 3000 |
| 2 | 4 | 500 |
| 2 | 5 | 700 |
| 2 | 6 | 900 |
| 3 | 7 | 300 |
| 3 | 8 | 400 |
| 3 | 9 | 500 |

**ProductTable**

| ProductID | ProductCategory |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Category1 |
| 2 | Category1 |
| 3 | Category2 |
| 4 | Category1 |
| 5 | Category3 |
| 6 | Category3 |
| 7 | Category4 |
| 8 | Category4 |
| 9 | Category2 |

**SupplierTable**

| SupplierID | SupplierNo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 102030 |
| 2 | 203040 |
| 3 | 304050 |

What I would like to do is select `SupplierNo` and `ProductCategory` based on the  highest max sum of the column `Revenue`, for each `Supplier`.

I think I have the "first level" of this query down, but need help with actually filtering rows where `Revenue` isn't `MAX(SUM))`. Right now, it is returning `MAX(SUM(Revenue))` but grouped by both `SupplierNo` and `ProductCategory`.

Query currently is:

```
WITH dim AS
(
    SELECT
        ProductID,
        SupplierID,
        SUM(Revenue) AS sumRevenue
    FROM
        DimensionTable
    GROUP BY
        ProductID, SupplierID
),
supp AS
(
    SELECT
        SupplierID,
        SupplierNo
    FROM
        SupplierTable
),
prod AS
(
    SELECT
        ProductID,
        ProductCategory
    FROM
        ProductTable
)
SELECT
    MAX(t1.sumRevenue) AS maxSumRevenue,
    t2.SupplierNo,
    t3.ProductCategory
FROM
    dim t1
LEFT JOIN
    supp t2 ON t1.SupplierID = t2.SupplierID
LEFT JOIN
    prod t3 ON t1.ProductID = t3.ProductID
GROUP BY
    t2.SupplierNo, t3.ProductCategory
ORDER BY 
    MAX(t1.sumRevenue) DESC;
```

Desired result:

| SupplierNo | ProductCategory | MAX(SUM(Revenue)) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102030 | Category2 | 3000 |
| 203040 | Category3 | 1600 |
| 304050 | Category4 | 700 |

So for each distinct `SupplierNo`, I want the `ProductCategory` with the highest value of `MAX(SUM(Revenue))`, and I want all three columns returned from the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for your need, your query would be like :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT SupplierNo
        ,ProductCategory
        ,SUM(Revenue) AS Revenue
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY SupplierNo ORDER BY SUM(Revenue) DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM DimensionTable d
    INNER JOIN ProductTable p ON d.ProductID = p.ProductID
    INNER JOIN SupplierTable s ON s.SupplierID = d.SupplierID
    GROUP BY SupplierNo
        ,ProductCategory
    ) a
WHERE rn = 1
```